# Join generic type with JPA and Criteria API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics, jpa, join

i'm trying to map the following entity:

I have an Order entity that contains different types of OrderData(can also be shared between multiple Order entities), depending on the actual order(different produckts, product variants etc):

```
//Simplified example
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderPK.class)
@Table(name = "tablename"
public class Order<T extends OrderData> {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "whatever")
    private T orderData;

    // Might be complicating stuff
    @Id
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "somecolumn")
    private Account buyerAccount;
    // ...
}

// OrderData base class
@Entity
@Table(name = "thatothertable"
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class OrderData {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // extra stuff
}
```

Now the problem is: how can i get this to join the right subclass of OrderData?
I want to be able to write something like this:
    `List<Order<CustomOrderData>> ordersWithCustomOrderData = this.orderDAO.findAllOrders();`
and get all Order entities with CustomOrderDatas.
Is there a way to achieve this?

So far my DAO codes looks like this:

```
public List<Order> findAllOrders() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
    Root<Order> root = cq.from(Order.class):
    cq.select(root):
    return this.em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

How would i have to change the DAO code to support the generic  type?
Is it actually possible? If not, is there any alternative design to achieve a comparable structure and functionability (Orders with different OrderDatas, ability to search for Orders with specific subclass of OrderData)?

```
// Not working pseudo code of what i want
public <T extends OrderData> List<Order<T>> findAllOrders() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    // With createQuery(Order.class) i will get CrtieriaQuery<Order>
    CriteriaQuery<Order<T>> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
    // as above
    Root<Order<T>> root = cq.from(Order.class):
    cq.select(root):
    return this.em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Idea**

Why do you need a generic Attribute? Generic entities are not possible in JPA but you could just put the reference to a Orderdata as:

`private OrderData orderData;`

**2. Idea**

You can save this enum in your entity and then compare `OrderDataType.getClazz()` to your `OrderData1.getClass()` and you can query for this types. If you are using JPA 2.1 you can save the full classname in the database column with a custom Fieldconverter and then query for the class.

```
public enum OrderDataType {
    Order1(Order1.class);

    private Class<? extends OrderData> clazz;

    private OrderDataType(Clazz<? extends OrderData> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends OrderData> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because most of the time i don't need all orders, only orders with a specific OrderData subclass. I would need to use instanceof and casts to achieve this: if (order.getOrderData() instanceof CustomOrderData) {((CustomerOrderData) order.getOrderData()).getCustomOrderDataOnlyField()}. I want to avoid this and be able to filter Orders based on the OrderData subclass. Or have something comparable.

Comment: Are the Options for OrderData limited? Are you are able to use a enum to determine the type?

Comment: Yes there will be around 3-5 subclasses of OrderData. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I ended up with something similar plus a bunch of constraints to make sure nothing gets mixed up.